# Swift tables click and pass information

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table in iOS. How to know what cell the user has clicked and pass information? I have been searching and I could find prepareForSegue. Is this the right method?. All the cases I could find were complicated and with a lot of elements. Can anyone apply to this simplified case and explain in a simple way, please. I am learning and for me is hard to understand this part.

```
 let favoriteThings = [
            "First",
            "Second",
            "Third",
 ]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.favoriteThings.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

// create a new instance of UITableViewCell. I give the name "cell" in Attributes > Identifier:
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FavoriteThingCell") as! UITableViewCell
var favoriteThingForRow = self.favoriteThings[indexPath.row]      
cell.textLabel?.text = favoriteThingForRow
return cell
}

// How to know what cell was clicked and pass the right information? Is this the right method?:

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

// the second screen. I select the icon of View Controller and Attributes Inspector > Class and Storyboard ID is: DetallViewController
var secondScene = segue.destinationViewController as! DetallViewController
if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
       let selected = favoriteThings[indexPath.row]
}

}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at did select row at index path method :)

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to implement the table view delegate method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. It's called by the runtime engine when the user taps a cell. In the method you can call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` and pass the `NSIndexPath` instance as parameter `sender`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    performSegueWithIdentifier("MyIdentifier", sender: indexPath)
}
```

The method `prepareForSegue:sender:` is also called automatically right before the segue is performed to be able to setup things. As you have the selected index path you can retrieve the appropriate datasource item

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  // the second screen. I select the icon of View Controller and Attributes Inspector > Class and Storyboard ID is: DetallViewController
  var secondScene = segue.destinationViewController as! DetallViewController
  let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath
  let selected = favoriteThings[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: I copy paste your code and it gives me the error "method does not override any method from its superclass". If I delete 'override' from func tableView then I can run but when I click to a row the line let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath gives an error 'Thread 1: signal SIGABRT' . I do not understand

Comment: my fault, delete the second override. In Interface Builder the source of the segue must be connected to the controller, not to the UITableViewCell.

Comment: No, the error was in the first override, not the second. But I still do not understand what does it mean.

Comment: `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is declared as `override func`. Replace "MyIdentifier" with the proper value in Interface Builder. If the segue is connected from the main view controller to the detail view controller rather than from the table view cell, the segue is performed in code with the appropriate index path